# Do wood ferns produce tubers?

Tags: ferns

I have large areas of a ferns , locally the name is wood fern. In moist shady locations in zone 8 it is invasive . It had covered a paver patio which I am trying to reclaim . As I rake , I find many spherical brown tubers about one inch in diameter. Are these tubers that can grow ferns ?  I have a neighbor that would like some . The tubers would be easier than moving root clumps which is how I have previously spread the ferns ( I do not like cutting grass , the ferns need no care ).

Comment: can you add a picture of the tubers?

Comment: Unfortunately ,I am a computer illiterate.